# what is the difference between .done() and .end() function in node and when they shall be used?

Tags: node.js, api, callback, mocha.js, supertest

I am trying to understand the use case of `end()` function while writing the API test script in mocha and Chai. Also at the same time, I am confused about whether I shall use the `done()` function here or not and also what is the exact difference between `.end()` and `.done()`.

Here's the code:

```js
describe("Suite", () => {
    it('Post Test case', (done) => {
        request('https://reqres.in')
        .post('/api/users')
        .send({
            "name": "morpheus",
            "job": "leader"
        })
        .set('Accept', 'application/json')
        .expect(200,'Content-Type', /json/)
        .then((err,res) => {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(err))
            console.log(JSON.stringify(res.body))
            console.log(JSON.stringify("           "))

        })
        done();
    });
    it('Put Test case', (done) => {
        request('https://reqres.in')
        .put('/api/users/2')
        .send({
            "name": "morpheus",
            "job": "zion residents"
        })
        .expect(200)
        .end((err, res) => {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(err))
            console.log(JSON.stringify(res.body))
            console.log(JSON.stringify("           "))

        })
        done();
    })
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixings things a little bit.

`end` is a method of the [expressjs framework](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.end) and it **ends** the server response.

`done` is a parameter of [mocha test function](https://mochajs.org/#asynchronous-code). You call this parameter when you are finished with your **asynchronous** test to let the `mocha` know that your asynchronous code is done executing, and it can move on to another test.

And in your case, you need them both.